# What design does ruby Monitor use for signal/wait?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Anyone better at reading ruby source code, or know the answer to this? (Please note, as far as I know it's got *nothing* to do with the GIL).

Ruby provides a [Monitor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/monitor/rdoc/Monitor.html), with ConditionVariables.

The [wikipedia article on Monitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) (which the ruby doc even references) says there are a couple different models/designs for how Monitors should work, with regard to which thread gets access to the mutual exclusion lock after a signal/wake.

[This article on Java](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-5-monitors-locks-and-conditions/) explains it pretty clearly (or maybe it's only clear if you've been beating your head against this stuff for a while):

- Signal & Continue (SC) : The process who signal keep the mutual exclusion and the signaled will be awaken but need to acquire the mutual exclusion before going.
- Signal & Wait (SW) : The signaler is blocked and must wait for mutual exclusion to continue and the signaled thread is directly awaken and can start continue its operations.

(And a couple more less common ones that are really variations on those two).

**Does anyone know which one ruby uses? It does not seem to be documented. Does it depend on ruby implementation (MRI vs jruby vs rubinius etc)?**

It does matter for certain designs. I think I had been beating my head against the wall because I had been assuming ruby used "SW" because that seemed 'obvious' to me, before I realized different implementations of 'Monitor' did it differently. Now, based on what I've been observing, I'm thinking ruby actually uses "SC" as above.

Meaning that after a signal is sent, while a thread will be awoken -- but there's no guarantee that thread will get the mutual exclusion lock *next*, some other random thread that was waiting on it might get it first.

If there are any gurus out there who can answer this for sure, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: _"This article on Java"_...which article?

Comment: bah, forgot the link, sorry, will add it.